# Download a file with JS

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm trying to download a remote mp3 file using JavaScript, but the problem is that I receive a cross origin error.
Here's my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
    var b64data = btoa(blob);
    zipFile.file(name, b64data, {base64: true});
    callback();
};

xhr.send();
```

It's an mp3 file so I don't care about not sending cookies or such.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, if the server implements the CORS spec, it's possible.  If it doesn't and you have no control over this server, then it is not possible.  In the latter case, you will need to proxy the file from a server you control instead.